# Импорт данных CSV формата, где в качестве десятичного разделителя выступает разделитель полей

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Подскажите, 
как сделать импорт данных csv формата, где в качестве разделителя числа выступает запятая и в качестве sep тоже запятая.
Если задавать только sep=','то число разбивается на два  столбца

Comment: Никак. Числа должны быть в кавычках.

Answer (score 1):

Если значения ячеек, содержащих запятую или другой символ-**разделитель** (именно тот, который используется в качестве разделителя полей), не обрамлены кавычками или другим спец. символом, то это не является корректным CSV файлом и не может быть прочитано стандартными средствами.

Пример **некорректного** файла, который, строго говоря, не является CSV:

```
ID,Price
1,1,99
2,9,99
```

Пример **корректного** CSV:

```
ID,Price
1,"1,99"
2,"9,99"
```

---

Если у вас корректный CSV и вопрос в том как прочитать числа, с запятой в качестве дестичного разделителями, как числа, а не как строки, то можно воспользоваться параметром `decimal=","`:

```
In [82]: df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Temp\data.csv", decimal=",")

In [83]: df
Out[83]:
   ID  Price
0   1   1.99
1   2   9.99

In [84]: df.dtypes
Out[84]:
ID         int64
Price    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: В теории если сильно постараться можно исправить такой неправильный файл. Но вообще говоря он не является CSV.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, это не всегда возможно - представьте что таких полей несколько или что присутствуют текстовые поля, которые тоже могут содержать запятую. В общем я как-то пробовал починить такой "CSV" программно и сдался в итоге...

Comment: Если взять за основу то, что будут только такие числа, а текста заканчивающего и начинающегося на цифры не будет, и не будет чисел подряд в сочетании с целыми без конечных нулей - задача вполне разрешимая.